# React how to keep track of the previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I want to know the previous state to know if I want to update a value.

I set up a tiny code example and I don't get it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
}

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  //the useRef Hook allows you to persist data between renders
  const prevCountRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    //assign the ref's current value to the count Hook
    prevCountRef.current = count;
  }, [count]); //run this code when the value of count changes
  return (
    <h1>
      Now: {count}, before: {prevCountRef.current}
      {/*Increment  */}
      <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </h1>
  );
}
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-thunder-30xfd7?file=/src/App.js:0-689)

What I don't get is why is prevCountRef is not the same after the setCount is set. In the useEffect I'm always saying both are equal.

Comment: `useEffect`s don't run until *after* the component renders. So while you're rendering, the ref still has the old value, and only once you're done do you set it to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you update the `count` state, the component re-renders, which causes the `useEffect` to be called, and update the `prevCountRef` to the current `count` value.

Remove the `useEffect` block, and save the current `count` to the ref before updating the state:

```
const prevCountRef = useRef(0); // initialize the prev value

<button onClick={() => setCount((count) => { 
  prevCountRef.current = count; // update the prev value
  return count + 1;
})}>Increment</button>
```